# How to explain the measure in sequence language

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Assume the measure $\mu$ defined on the $(\mathbb{N},2^\mathbb{N})$ and define the $$x_{n}=\mu(\{n\}),$$
>
> (a)How to describe $\mu$ in sequence language the $x_{n}$ when $\mu$ is a measure, finite, $\sigma-$finite, or non-semi-finite.
>
> (b)What properties are required of a sequence $x_n$ such that $\mu(\{n\}):=x_{n}$ defines a complete, semifinite measure on $2^\mathbb{N}$?

I am confused about the $\mu(\{1\}\cup \{2\})=\mu(\{1\})+ \mu(\{2\})=x_1+x_2$. How to describe $x_{n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any sequence $(x_n)$ of non-negative numbers there is always a measure $\mu$ with $\mu \{n\}=x_n$. This measure is always sigma finite (and semi finite) and it is finite iff $\sum x_n <\infty$.

To construct $\mu$ define $\mu (A)=\sum_{n \in A} x_n$. The fact that this set function is countably additive follows easily from the following:

Lemma

If $a_{nm} \geq 0$ for all $n,m$ the n$\sum_m \sum_n a_{nm}=\sum_n\sum_m a_{nm}$.

Some more details:

Let $A$ be the union of a disjoint sequence $(A_n)$. We have to show that $\sum_{ n \in A}  x_n=\sum_k \sum_{ n \in A_k}  x_n$. This can be written as $\sum_{ n \in A}  x_n= \sum_k \sum_n x_n I_{A_k} (n)$. By the lemma the right hand side is $ \sum_n \sum_k x_n I_{A_k} (n)$ which is same as the left side because $\sum_k x_n I_{A_k} (n)= x_n$ if $n \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Why is this claim true? Is there any more detail? Thanks.

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui I have added some details.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I also have a question that What properties are required of a sequence $x_n$ such that $\mu(\{n\}):=x_{n}$ defines a complete, semifinite measure on $2^\mathbb{N}$? I think the $x_n$ are required to be positive. And if $\mu$ is complete, that is any $A\in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, $\sum_{n\in A}x_n=0$, then $\sum_{n\in B}x_n=0, B\subset A$. And $\mu$ is semifinite, that is any $A\in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, $\sum_{n\in A}x_n=\infty$, then there exists $B\subset A$ such that $0<\sum_{n\in B}x_n<\infty$. Are there any other requirements?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui No need for $x_n>0$. $\mu$ is always semi-finite and complete.

Comment: $\mu$ be complete is easy to see. But how to let $\mu$ be semifinite? Does $B$ always exist such that $0<\sum_{n\in B} x_{n}<\infty$?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui If $\sum_{n \in A} x_n=\infty$ then there exists $k \in A$ such that $x_k>0$.  Take $B=\{x_k\}$.

Comment: But if $x_{n}$ is not positive, is $\mu(\{n\})$ a measure?

Comment: Do you mean $B=\{k\}$?

Comment: Also, if $x_{i}$ is not positive, it is hard to show that the complete of $\mu$. Because $\sum_{n\in A}x_{n}=0$ does not show that $\sum_{n\in B}x_{n}=0, \forall B\subset A$

Comment: @LoveQYG $0 \leq \sum_{n \in B} x_n \leq \sum_{n \in A} x_0$.

Comment: Can I understand the positive of $x_{n}$ is automatic? Because of $\mu$ is a measure, then $\mu(\{n\})=x_n\geq 0$. So $\sum_{n\in B} x_n \geq 0$.

Comment: Yes, that is right.